# SpriteKit animation

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit

I need your advice, I'm new in SpriteKit  I need to make animation strips. I have 3 solutions to make it, but I need advice that better and less costly for  CPU.

- 1 solution: each stripe - SKSpriteNode with animation and texture
- 2 solution: background video
- 3 solution: each stripe - SKShapeNode with animation

[image]

Comment: The highest performance in terms of CPU usage would be use of a series of PNG images that are decoded before hand and then animate with SKAction. The downside with this approach is lots of memory usage. A background video will likely not be able to handle 60 FPS framerate. The SKShapeNode approach can consume a lot of CPU because each frame needs to be rendered.

Comment: simple colored sprites are faster than textured ones and they can be made any dimension.

Comment: @MoDJ I would agree that in this case, no textures are needed...

Comment: I don't know exactly what the original poster wants to do, if this person goes with approach 3, to render shapes from vector information, then no textures would be needed. But, rendering from a vector may or may not be faster, it all depends on the implementation. I know a background video will not work at that FPS rate.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple task , you don't need to build an atlas animation or use `SKShapeNode`, you can use `SKSpriteNode` as this code:

```
var bar = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.greenColor(), size: CGSizeMake(40, 200))
barra.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
self.addChild(barra)
```

Build n bars with random size, and use `SKAction` to move them.

Whith this approach your animation will be different everytime you launch it.

**Code in details**:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var bars: [SKSpriteNode]!
    var totBars : Int = 50
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor(red: 131/255, green: 190/255, blue: 177/255, alpha: 1)
        let redBarColor = SKColor(red: 204/255, green: 75/255, blue: 75/255, alpha: 1)
        let yellowBar = SKColor(red: 253/255, green: 242/255, blue: 160/255, alpha: 1)
        // add here your colors
        var colorSelected:SKColor = redBarColor
        bars = [SKSpriteNode]()
        for i in 0..<totBars-1 {
            let colorNum = randomNumber(1...2)
            switch (colorNum) {
            case 1:
                colorSelected = redBarColor
            case 2:
                colorSelected = yellowBar
            default:
            break
            }
            let randomWidth = randomCGFloat(5,max:40)
            let randomHeight = randomCGFloat(30,max:400)
            let bar = SKSpriteNode.init(color: colorSelected, size: CGSizeMake(randomWidth, randomHeight))
            bar.zRotation = -45 * CGFloat(M_PI / 180.0)
            bar.name = "bar\(i)"
            self.addChild(bar)
            bars.append(bar)
        }
        animateBars()
    }
    func animateBar(bar:SKSpriteNode) {
        print("- \(bar.name) start!")
        let deltaX = self.randomCGFloat(0,max:self.frame.maxX)
        let deltaY:CGFloat  = self.frame.maxY/2
        let rightPoint = CGPointMake(self.frame.maxX + deltaX,self.frame.maxY + deltaY)
        let leftPoint = CGPointMake(-self.frame.maxX + deltaX,-self.frame.maxY + deltaY)
        bar.position = rightPoint
        let waitBeforeExit = SKAction.waitForDuration(Double(self.randomCGFloat(1.0,max:2.0)))
        let speed = self.randomCGFloat(150,max:300)
        let move = SKAction.moveTo(leftPoint, duration: self.getDuration(rightPoint, pointB: leftPoint, speed: speed))
        bar.runAction(SKAction.sequence([waitBeforeExit,move]), completion: {
           print("\(bar.name) reached position")
           self.animateBar(bar)
        })
    }
    func animateBars() {
        for bar in bars {
            animateBar(bar)
        }
    }
    func getDuration(pointA:CGPoint,pointB:CGPoint,speed:CGFloat)->NSTimeInterval {
        let xDist = (pointB.x - pointA.x)
        let yDist = (pointB.y - pointA.y)
        let distance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
        let duration : NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(distance/speed)
        return duration
    }
    func randomCGFloat(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX)) * (max - min) + min
    }
    func randomNumber(range: Range<Int> = 1...6) -> Int {
        let min = range.startIndex
        let max = range.endIndex
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min))) + min
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. I think skspitenode it's a better way, but I doubt about it

Comment: What's your doubts?

Comment: About performance. I had a lot of problems with cpu performance, and i want find the best solutions for this

Comment: If you need you can download the project source here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=51158577123132911392

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I just wanted to point out the clever way you work with the colors,  Never thought of doing something like that when dealing with floats!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If your stripes are simply plain rectangles, you can use `SKSpriteNodes` and only give them dimensions and a color, then use actions to animate them.  you can rotate the rectangles to give the effect you show in the picture.

You could actually build the whole animation in Xcode using the editor, save it in its own SKS file and load the animation using a `SKReferenceNode`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, Solution 3 is the least costly method for your CPU. Here're several reasons why this is true:

**1.** The first solution that you're suggesting `SKSpriteNode` with animation and texture" require the computer to load the texture to the view. If you have multiple `.png` files, this would mean that the computer would need to load all of these files. But if you were to use `SKShapeNode`, you would avoid having to do this and you would cheaply create the same looks as the `SKShapeNode` is not based on an image.

**2.** Solution 2 is the most costly to your CPU because running a video. This takes a lot of space in your memory which might even create lags if you run it on your phone.

Also, just another thing to note: If you were to extensively use Solution 1 and 2, you would end up using so much memory. But if you use the Solution 3, you will not deal with this.

Comment: Actually, `SKShapeNode` is the worst solution here no matter what. It requires one draw call per node and will degrade  performance greatly if not used sparingly... By the way, why would you ever use `SKShapeNode` for this particular case, instead of a colored `SKSpriteNode` which, unlike `SKShapeNode` can be rendered in batches ? IMO, `SKShapeNode` is not even worth of mentioning for the current problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, in addition to the ones put forth already, would be to write a GLSL shader for the background.  If you just want a cool backdrop that doesn't interact with the rest of your game, this would probably be the most performant option, since it would all happen on the GPU.

You could even, conceivably, render the rectangles without requiring any images at all, since they are just areas of color.

There's a decent introduction to the topic here: [Battle of Brothers GLSL Introduction](http://battleofbrothers.com/sirryan/understanding-shaders-in-spritekit).